# Accessing post query params in Azure webhook

Tags: powershell, query-string, azure-webhooks

I am trying to **read the URL query params from a POST** coming into my **Azure webhook** (PowerShell).

My webhook is receiving a POST request such as:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
POST https://{notificationUrl}?validationToken={opaqueTokenCreatedByMicrosoftGraph}
```

As you may tease out, the context here is the creation of a [Microsoft Graph subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation). However, I don't want to muddy up this post with too many details because I think my question is general enough: how to read POST params in an Azure webhook.

The runbook attached to this webhook ([based on this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#create-a-webhook)) apparently requires all the client data to come in via a single parameter called `WebhookData`. I am able to read the `WebhookName`, `RequestBody`, and `RequestHeader` inside `WebhookData`. However, I don't know how to read the URL query parameter in the POST request that is reaching my webhook.

Specifically, I need to access that `validationToken`. It doesn't show up in the `WebhookData`. I've also tried removing the `Webhookdata` param altogether from my runbook, but then absolutely nothing comes in. I've also tried adding a `validationToken` param, alongside the `WebhookData` param, but `validationToken` comes out empty.

I should add that, along with the POST from Graph (which doesn't work), I am testing my runbook with Postman and making sure to include a `validationToken` in the URL. Again, I can read it if I include it in the POST body, but not if it's a query param. And since ultimately Graph will be sending it via the query param, I think I have to get that to work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very specifically, `Azure Runbooks`, do not support query strings. [From the documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks#parameters-used-when-the-webhook-starts-a-runbook)

> To receive data from the client, the runbook **supports a single**
> **parameter called `WebhookData`**. This parameter defines an object
> containing data that the client includes in a POST request.
>
> The `WebhookData` parameter has the following properties:

| Property | Description |
| --- | --- |
| WebhookName | Name of the webhook. |
| RequestHeader | Hashtable containing the headers of the incoming POST request. |
| RequestBody | Body of the incoming POST request. This body keeps any data formatting, such as string, JSON, XML, or form-encoded. The runbook must be written to work with the data format that is expected. |

`Azure Runbooks` has 2 parts to it, triggers and runbooks:

[image: Azure Runbooks]

The `Runbook` (Right Box) only accepts the single `WebhookData` object to manage variable and data that `Azure Runbooks` will operate with.

`Webhooks` (Left Box), handles the triggering, receiving of data and passing it on to the `Runbook`. Very specifically, the `RequestBody` is specified as the:

> Body of the incoming POST request. This body keeps any data
> formatting, such as string, JSON, XML, or form-encoded.This body keeps
> any data formatting, such as string, JSON, XML, or form-encoded.

With this definition, very specifically, even though `WebHooks` can support query strings, in this case for triggering `Azure Runbooks` they are explicitly ignored.

---

Aside, if the end desire is to subscribe to Microsoft Graph events, the "better" way is to use `Event Hubs` to [handle notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery):

> Using Azure Event Hubs to receive change notifications differs from
> webhooks in a few ways, including:
>
> - You don't rely on publicly exposed notification URLs. The Event Hubs SDK will relay the notifications to your application.
> - **You don't need to reply to the notification URL validation. You can ignore the validation message that you receive.**
> - You'll need to provision an Azure Event Hub.
> - You'll need to provision an Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Thanks HAL9256 for this info. I will digest it a bit and most likely mark your reply as the answer. So I guess this confirms in my scenario the webhook cannot read in the query params. I will have to look into the Event Hubs if that is considered the best practice.